# Signup page only allows the test email and password

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I couldn't connect to firebase at all and make let the users create accounts with the signup functions and I had asked my friend for help.. He did some and it connected to firebase but now it only says the email you used is already in use.. I want it to let users type in their own email and be able to create an account..

```
<h2>Make an account with us or log in</h2>
<div class="container" id="container">
  <div class="form-container sign-up-container">
    <form action="#">
      <h1>Create Account</h1>
      <span>or use your email for registration</span>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="signupName"  >
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="signupEmail"  />
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="signupPassword"  />
<input type="button" id="signup" value= "signup" onclick="signUp()"/>
      <button onsubmit="signup()">signUp</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="form-container sign-in-container">
    <form action="#">
      <h1>Sign in</h1>
      <span>or use your account</span>
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="loginEmail"  />
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="loginPassword" />
      <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
      <button>Sign In</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="overlay-container">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="overlay-panel overlay-left">
        <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>
        <p>To keep connected with us please login with your personal info</p>
        <button class="ghost" id="signIn">Sign In</button>
      </div>
      <div class="overlay-panel overlay-right">
        <h1>Hello, Friend!</h1>
        <p>Enter your personal details and start journey with us</p>
        <button class="ghost" id="signUp">Sign Up</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here's the CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,800');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background:white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: -20px 0 50px;
}

h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
}

p {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    margin: 20px 0 30px;
}

span {
    font-size: 12px;
}

a {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 15px 0;
}

button {
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #FF4B2B;
    background-color: #FF4B2B;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 12px 45px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: transform 80ms ease-in;
}

button:active {
    transform: scale(0.95);
}

button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

button.ghost {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
}

form {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 50px;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

input {
    background-color: #eee;
    border: none;
    padding: 12px 15px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.container {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 
            0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 768px;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 480px;
}

.form-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.sign-in-container {
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    z-index: 2;
}

.container.right-panel-active .sign-in-container {
    transform: translateX(100%);
}

.sign-up-container {
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.container.right-panel-active .sign-up-container {
    transform: translateX(100%);
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 5;
    animation: show 0.6s;
}

@keyframes show {
    0%, 49.99% {
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    
    50%, 100% {
        opacity: 1;
        z-index: 5;
    }
}

.overlay-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 100;
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay-container{
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.overlay {
    background: #FF416C;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #FF4B2B, #FF416C);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #FF4B2B, #FF416C);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 0 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
    left: -100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200%;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay {
    transform: translateX(50%);
}

.overlay-panel {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 40px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.overlay-left {
    transform: translateX(-20%);
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay-left {
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.overlay-right {
    right: 0;
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay-right {
    transform: translateX(20%);
}

.social-container {
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.social-container a {
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 5px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}

footer {
    background-color: #222;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 999;
}

footer p {
    margin: 10px 0;
}

footer i {
    color: red;
}

footer a {
    color: #3c97bf;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

and the actual js that my friend did

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.5.0/firebase-app.js";
import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.5.0/firebase-analytics.js";
import { initializeAuth, getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.5.0/firebase-auth.js";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "firebear-34281.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://firebear-34281-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "firebear-34281",
    storageBucket: "firebear-34281.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "642455892026",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: "G-ZHVQEHH0FQ"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);

const auth = getAuth();
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, 'test@test.com', 'password')
    .then((userCredential) => {
    // Signed in 
    const user = userCredential.user;
    alert('Signed in');
    // ...
})
    .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    alert(error)
    // ..
    });
```

Comment: `createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, 'test@test.com', 'password')`
Well with this line you are creating a user with the same email each time so its already in use

Comment: I figured that but like what do I change so that it creates user with whatever is written in the text field